# Fixing ActionView::MissingTemplate without render nothing?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

I ran into ActionView::MissingTemplate early on in my development, and used render nothing: true to fix it. It works great right now, the only thing is  I have to send errors via a json render in some cases, and then I end up with a DoubleRenderError. I also understand that some use head: ok, but that is not working either. Is there an alternate way to deal with this error? Any and all help is appreciated. Cheers~

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should only get a `DoubleRenderError` if both render calls are getting hit, which you may be able to solve with a condition:

```
if errors.present?
  render json: errors
else
  render nothing: true
end
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed ... never worked with rendering before but makes perfect sense